# increasing total unload class in JConsole increase

Tags: java, jconsole

i am using JConsole monitoring my application and i found the total unload class are increasing from time to time. and the heap size and used heap are increasing too. after sometime, my application crashed.

do anyone have a idea why is this happen? does this implies there is something like a memory leak ?

thank you

Comment: Have you profiled with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)?

Comment: yes i try to do it and see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is memory leak. Are you seeing any increase in heap usage in jconsole? class unloading may happen in case where classloader is GCed (or) those classes designated as soft references.  Here are couple of interesting discussion on why class unloading happens [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833983/meaning-of-the-unloading-class-messages).

Comment: i can see the heap size and used heap size are increasing  by time.but yes it does not imply there is a memory link.thanks.